# .NET ClaimsAuthenticationManager and Dependency Injection

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity

Following is skeleton of ClaimsAuthenticationManager

```
namespace ABC
{
    public class ClaimsTransformer : ClaimsAuthenticationManager
    {
        private IUow _iUow;

        public ClaimsTransformer(IUow uow)
        {
            this._iUow = uow;
        }

        public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Unity.Mvc5 for IoC container. Injecting dependency works fine for Controller.

But DI is not working for ClaimsAuthenticationManager. I get following error

```
Parser Error Message: ID1024: The configuration property value is not valid.
Property name: 'type'
Error: 'Constructor on type 'ABC.ClaimsTransformer' not found.'
```

How can I inject dependency to ClaimsAuthenticationManager?

Answer (score 1):

I've not used Unity but you can use the ServiceLocator in instances where the instantiation of the object is not within your control. Register the ServiceLocator in your Application_Start()

```
protected void Application_Start()
{            
    UnityServiceLocator locator = new UnityServiceLocator(ConfigureUnityContainer());
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator);            
}

private static IUnityContainer ConfigureUnityContainer()
{
    UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    return container;
}
```

Then in your ClaimsTransformer you should be able to call the ServiceLocator to resolve your Uow within your ClaimsTransformer

```
public class ClaimsTransformer : ClaimsAuthenticationManager   
{
    public IUow UnitOfWork
    {
        get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUow>(); }
    }

    public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

See [CommonServiceLocator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) for details.

[Here](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Unity%20Adapter&referringTitle=Home) for the Unity implementation.

Nuget: PM> Install-Package CommonServiceLocator.UnityAdapter

I haven't run this code but it should point you in the right direction.